# Checking node_env in node.js

Tags: node.js

[image]

[image]

Hello, I set the NODE_ENV in my dev env as development. When I console log the NODE_ENV it give me development, but when I do a compare it gives me false. Does anybody know what is it happening?

Comment: "_I set the NODE_ENV in my dev env as development_": How are you configuring the environment variable and how are you running your program? Please update your question to include text representations of all relevant source code, configuration files, run commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to set the variable of NODE_ENV first.

like if you using windows

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
```

or Mac/linux

```
export NODE_ENV=development
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this if the `NODE_ENV = "development "` instead of "development", and when you `conosle.log` it you will not be able to see the space after it.

You can trim it:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() or process.env.NODE_ENV?.trim()
```

So the code will be like this:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() == 'development'
```